# DocuSign for Salesforce Custom Button for Partner Community

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi

I'm rolling out `DocuSign` (specifically for our Partner Community users) and have discovered that the Apex flows that come out of the box are not being referenced in the button as Partner users operate out of a force.com site.

I'm a *clicks-not-code* guy and am attempting to create the custom button to resolve this based on some suggestions.  The code I've created is spawning an error:

> "A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered: Unterminated regular expression literal"

Here's the code I have:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var
CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//
// Modify individual options here: //
// Related Content (default no related content) //
RC = GetRelContentIDs("{!Opportunity.Id}");
//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID{!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"
&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

David

Answer (score 0):

I know officially DocuSign does not support partner communities, but try something like the below, it's a standard button that works on any SFDC object.

> {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
>
> //********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//  var RC =
>   '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var
>   CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var
>   CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var
>   SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';var sourceId=''; 
>   //*************************************************//
>
> var sourceId = DSGetPageIDFromHref();
>
> //********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
>   window.location.href
>   ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID="+sourceId+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
>   //*******************************************//